# Keeping image aspect ratios intact while using Scrolling Parallax jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, parallax

I am using the [Scrolling Parallax jQuery plugin](http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin) to scroll the "background" image (not actually a css background-image) on [this site](http://indigobrazilianportuguese.com).

Is it possible to maintain the image aspect ratio, i.e. not squash the images, and still have it work in all modern browsers?

I tried setting `bgHeight : 'auto'` which sets the image css to `height:auto`, but this stops the scrolling effect working in Chrome and Safari.

I also tried setting `bgWidth : 'auto'` but then the image is narrower than the browser window.

Also open to other plugins or ways to implement this effect, i.e. having the background image scroll at a different rate to the page content, and also to show the entire image, but not scroll past it...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What if you put the image in body background & use background-size:cover;

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: can you set % for width or height?

Comment: +1 for well written Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the width is automatically set to be 100% of the viewport, stretching will occur unless you change that.

Use this:

```
$.scrollingParallax('img/clouds.png', {
    bgHeight : '250%',
    staticSpeed : .25,
    staticScrollLimit : false,
    bgWidth: 'auto'
});
```

The above can be seen in action here: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hAP7C/2/)

---

Since a non-stretched background image is always floating left, I whipped up some jQuery goodness so the image is centered in the viewport at all times, even during **Window Resize Event**. That said, the image will now scale up to the maximum image size or shrink while preserving Aspect Ratio in all browsers.

```
$(function() {

    // Specify your background image here.
    var bgMain = 'http://indigobrazilianportuguese.com/2012/wp-content/uploads/Home_bg1600.jpg';

    $.scrollingParallax(bgMain, {
        bgHeight : '200%',
        staticSpeed : 0.25,
        staticScrollLimit : false,
        // Important to set to 'auto' so Aspect Ratio for width is preserved because height defined above is fixed.
        bgWidth: 'auto'
    });

    // These two lines is for page load.
    // The variable will calculate CSS 'left' for the background image to center it in the viewport.
    // First, horizontal viewport size is checked via $(window).width()
    // Then, image width is determined by searching for image's unique filepath/filename.
    // Once the different is known, this value is then divided by 2 so that equal space is seen on left and right side of image which becomes the variable value.
    var bgMainHcenter = ( $(window).width() - $('body img[src="' + bgMain + '"]').width() ) /2 ;
    $('body img[src="' + bgMain + '"]').css('left', bgMainHcenter + 'px');

    // Just like above, it's repeated during Window Resize Event.
    $(window).resize(function() {
        bgMainHcenter = ( $(window).width() - $('body img[src="' + bgMain + '"]').width() ) /2 ;
        $('body img[src="' + bgMain + '"]').css('left', bgMainHcenter + 'px');
    });

});
```

**See it in action here:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hAP7C/3/)

Comment: Thanks arttronics, but as I mentioned in my question when I set the `bgWidth` to `auto` the image displays narrower than the browser window (even with `bgHeight` set to `200%`)

Comment: Opps... I rushed to provide just a snippet answer without reading your full question which warranted a full answer. That said, I now provide complete example markup and jsFiddle that is cross-browser friendly. If you still have issue on your website, include `bgWidth` as shown above and I will look to see what's the matter.

Comment: Reminder: **Always** press the **Run Button** in jsFiddle after the page loads to insure the code is launched correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome artronics! I just wrapped the first image centering function in `$(window).load(function(){` to get it to work on my site http://indigobrazilianportuguese.com - is this the best practice?

Comment: If the image would not load otherwise then the method you choose is sound and is equivalent to non-jQuery `window.onload=function(){};`. That said, try using `window.onload` method instead to see if images load faster? Two side tips. 1) 300% zoom makes image blurry and very little of [**original image**](http://indigobrazilianportuguese.com/2012/wp-content/uploads/Home_bg1600.jpg) is shown: Consider less percent and have unique `background-color` for when bars are exposed on the sides. 2) Click [**jsLint**](http://jsfiddle.net/YdUVP/) to see that many semicolons are missing in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

ok so according to their homepage you can set % for width and height so I would try that first and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Haungism. I tried `%` first, but then that loses the image aspect ratio when the browser window is resized.